# Lucene indexing service

Tags: service, lucene

We want to use lucene in our J2EE web application. We want create separate lucene service(Which will be deployed in separate JBOSS server) for Lucene related functionality (like indexwriting/searching documents).
We will call lucene service from Our JEEE applcation for lucene related funcationality.

What is the best way to communicate between two application? RMI/http/webservice or any other?

Please give some thoughts..

Answer (score 2):

Don't reinvent the wheel. use [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).